# Showing two integrals are equal as n tends to infinity:

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\frac{\sin{2nt}}{\sin{t}}dt\approx\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin{u}}{u}du$$

I have to show this is true for large n as the last part of a question on Fourier Series.

Any hints as to what substitution to try would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, I would consider letting $w=2nt$ on the LHS. This results in two integrals that are identical except for the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We change the variable $u=2nt$ for the integral on the LHS we get

$$\frac1{2n}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin u}{\sin(u/2n)}du=\int_0^{\pi}g_n(u)\frac{\sin u}{u}du$$
where
$$g_n(u)=\frac{u/2n}{\sin(u/2n)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$
and since the function $x\mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is bounded then

$$\left|g_n(u)\frac{\sin u}{u}\right|\le M\frac{\sin u}{u}\in L^1(0,\pi)$$
so by the dominated convergence theorem we get the desired result.